# I installed Nim without any problem, but it gives me this error, what should I do?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, nim-lang

I install Nim Lang but it not works. I get this errors, how can i fix? (I have completed the setup.)

```
Error: invocation of external compiler program failed. Sistem belirtilen dosayayi bulamiyor.
Additional info: "Requested command not found: \'gcc.exe -c  -w -fmax-errors=3 -mno-ms-bitfields   -I\"C:\\Program Files\\Nim Language\\lib\" -IC:\\Users\\SyTax\\Desktop -o C:\\Users\\Sytax\Desktop -o C:\\Users\\SyTax\\nimcache\\name_d\\stdlib_io.nim.c.o C:\\Users\\SyTax\\nimcache\\name_d\\stdlib_io.nim.c\'. OS error:" 2
```

Error;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgkk0.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your error messages as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Comment: Even better, a [mcve] showing exactly how you generated the error would maximize your chances of getting a useful answer here.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Probably you only installed the first package from [Nim's windows installation page](https://nim-lang.org/install_windows.html). Note that there are other dependencies mentioned on that page. You may also need:

- MingW compiler dependency, installed with `finish.exe`.
- DLLs available on your system, like PCRE or OpenSSL, also available for download.

Alternatively you could try installing Nim using [Scoop](https://scoop.sh), which seems to be able to install both Nim and the required compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The Nim compiler creates C code, so to compile your code to binary and run, you should install a C compiler. The default is GCC. In linux and mac, it comes with the system, so I am assuming you are using windows.

I am not a Windos user, but AFAIK you neet to install mingw amd gcc

http://www.codebind.com/cprogramming/install-mingw-windows-10-gcc/

http://mingw.org/

Comment: I don't know how to do this. But I will try, thanks for your help.